# How to access a stateful bean in a listener

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a Java EE project with an EJB containing a Remote Stateful Bean.

I have an enterprise application with a GUI.

I have listener in my GUI but my problem is that I can't access to my Bean in a button listener (to check username and password).

I use netBeans and glassFish.

To lookup beans I use:

```
ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/BeanStateful");
```

But apparently the listener change the context and it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: So the GUI is an external Java Desktop program which access the remote EJBs. Mmmm, can you post some code? Are you able to access remote EJBs **outside** the listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listener is probably running on a thread that does not have a JavaEE context.  Try obtaining the java:comp/env Context from the main thread, and then only lookup() the bean name from the listener.  For example:

```
// Member variables
private Context _javaCompEnvContext;
...

// Main thread
_javaCompEnvContext = ctx.lookup("java:comp/comp/env");
...

// Listener thread
BusinessIntf bean = _javaCompEnvContext.lookup("BeanStateful");
```

Comment: You know, i realise i have no idea what constitutes a session when using RMI. Is this covered in the spec somewhere? Or rather, where in the spec is this covered? Anyone know?

Comment: An SFSB will expire after a configurable amount of time (@StatefulTimeout in EJB 3.1), but they can also be removed explicitly (@Remove method).  The SFSB lifecycle is independent of local vs remote, and it's also independent of an HTTP session.  Some vendors do a better job of integrating HTTP session with SFSB than others.